# Hamburger Menu at bottom of screen (Tab Bar)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've seen lots of libraries on github with hamburger menus at the top left or right of the ios screen (SWRevealViewController: https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController). Is there a library that can implement it at the bottom of the screen where the tab bar is located?

Similar to this image below

[image]

Comment: why was this downvoted? please provide an explanation....

Comment: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's quite a few libraries on [cocoapods](https://cocoapods.org) that support the tray effect you are looking for - which can be fiddly to implement.  Almost all of them will trigger the opening and closing of the tray with a button of your choice.  Where is sits it totally up to you.